# Cross-Compiling Qt Applications from Windows to Mac OS

Tags: qt, cross-compiling

Can anyone tell me how to build `.app` extension files through Qt Creator-SDK and MingW? GCC Compiler is also installed.

I have done is

```
qmake -spec macx-xcode project_name.pro
```

It created supporting files to create `.app` extension (when opened in Notepad).

Thank You.

Comment: So what is not working? Please be more precise about the problem you have, what you are saying is that `qmake` did the right thing - but not what's not working after that.

Comment: What to do after this step??I am totally totally lost. Googleing too didnt help..

Comment: Please follow a tutorial, and try building for windows first. If you don't know what to do after that step, cross-compiling is probably too complex a target right now - you'll need to understand the build process a bit more before attempting that.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [CMake](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-snapshot/creator-project-cmake.html): it does what it says on the tin: cross-platform make. Integrates nicely with Qt (it's what KDE uses).

Comment: Did you actually try this - compiling with CMake on Windows for Mac? My Mac has a Apple-supplied gcc which will not work on Windows.